# Why NavigationLink background is grey?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm following SwiftUI [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/composing-complex-interfaces#add-navigation-between-sections) to create my first app with SwiftUI but on TVOs and I don't know why but the scroll view item are with background color in grey, and when they are focussed they become white.
I don't find the way to change the color...

Can you help me please ?

[image]

My code :

```
struct LigneCategorie: View {
    var nomCategorie: String
    var items: [Recette]

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(self.nomCategorie)
                .font(.headline)
                .padding(.leading, 15)
                .padding(.top, 5)

            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                    ForEach(self.items) { recette in
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: RecetteDetail(
                                recette: recette
                            )
                        ) {
                            CategoryItem(recette: recette)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 185)
        }
    }
}


struct CategoryItem: View {
    var recette: Recette
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            recette.image
                .renderingMode(.original)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 200, height: 150)
                .cornerRadius(10)
            Text(recette.name)
                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                .font(.caption)
        }
        .padding(.leading, 15)

    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can set your school view's background in a preview side. when you click your scroll view you would  see a chosen scroll view in preview mode Font,color and similar options must to be appear. But if not, then   try this it should be useful.

```
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
}.color(.gray)
```